# Turning incomplete lines into new columns on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Folks,

I have converted a PDF using tabula-py and, due to the formatting (there are two lines with names in each name cell) I get this:

```
col1  name      doc  col4  col5  col6
XXX   John Doe  XXX  XXX   XXX   XXX
NaN   Jane Way  YYY  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I want to turn the two filled columns on the rows with NaN into new columns on the full rows before (name2 and doc2, maybe). Like this:

```
col1  name      doc  col4  col5  col6  name2     doc2
XXX   John Doe  XXX  XXX   XXX   XXX   Jane Way  YYY
```

I thought of separating the filled and unfilled rows into different dataframes, then merging, but I don't think it applies, since the number of columns with NaNs is different of the number of columns without them.

The best way would be, when there is a NaN on the first column, to attribute the filled values to new columns in the previous row.

One thing I tried, that didn't work (Python didn't recognize the new column name as something valid):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(np.NaN, '|')
for i in range(len(df)):
  if df['col1'][i] == '|':
    df['name2'][i-1] = df['name'][i]
    df['doc2'][i-1] = df['doc'][i]
```

Comment: It might be easier if you show an example of what your desired output looks like

Comment: Sure! Correcting now.

Comment: is it only ever 2 names? Can there be 3?

Comment: I only met two. When there is one name, as far as I've seen, the slot for the second name seems to show up as "*********"

Comment: In some cases, down the road, the names are like "JOHN DOE\rJANE WAY"

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
  col1      name  doc col4 col5 col6
0  XXX  John Doe  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
1  NaN  Jane Way  YYY  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you do:

```
pd.concat([df[0::2], df[1::2]], axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all').bfill().dropna()
```

Output:

```
  col1      name  doc col4 col5 col6      name  doc
0  XXX  John Doe  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX  Jane Way  YYY
```

You can rename the columns as needed~

Comment: Hm. NEARLY worked, but the result it is giving me is from this:

`  col1      name  doc col4 col5 col6`  
`0  XXX  John Doe  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX`  
`1  NaN  Jane Way  YYY  NaN  NaN  NaN`
`2  ZZZ  Jim Bang  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ  ZZZ`
`3  NaN  Jay Hill  NaN NaN  NaN NaN`  
`4  WWW  Joe Meek  WWW WWW  WWW WWW`  

To this:

`  col1      name  doc col4 col5 col6  name2      doc2`  
`0  XXX  John Doe  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX  Jane Way    YYY`  
`1  ZZZ  Jim Bang  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ  ZZZ  Jane Way YYY`
`2  ZZZ  Jim Bang  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ  ZZZ  Jay Hill AAA`
`3  WWW  Joe Meek  WWW WWW  WWW  WWW  Jay Hill AAA`